# Cassandra: can I have default value for a column like sql

Tags: cassandra

During the creation of a table, like in SQL we have **DEFAULT** to insert a defualt value for a column.
type tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Is there anything to achieve the same in Cassandra .

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, there is no default value in Cassandra. Further more, setting a column value to *null* means removing it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so setting of the required column value have to be taken care from the code