# Cassandra default column value cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I am very new to Cassandra, and using the cqlsh to try out basic queries. I want to alter a table by inserting a new column with a default value (say 0). This is same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155691/cassandra-can-i-have-default-value-for-a-column-like-sql), the difference being I am trying to do it from cqlsh, so can't run an insert command on 50,000 rows. Is there a "cqlish" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no cqlsh/cql driver ways to this at the moment without executing on all of your rows. The simplest way may be to use a Spark and the Cassandra Connector.

There you could do something like

```
case class RowObj( oldValue1: Type, ..., newDefaultValue: Type)
sc.cassandraTable[RowObj]("keyspace","table")
    .map(row -> row.copy(newDefaultValue = default)
    .saveToCassandra("keyspace","table")
```