# Cassandra: backfilling new boolean field

Tags: cassandra

I added a new boolean column called `subscribe` to my `email_subscriptions` table in Cassandra. I noticed that it returns `false` for all rows' `subscribe` field.

I wanted to default all rows in the table with the `subscribe` field as true, but [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155691/cassandra-can-i-have-default-value-for-a-column-like-sql) says:

> there is no default value in Cassandra.

So my question is, how do I set all rows in my `email_subscriptions` table to have their `subscribe` field set to `true`? Do I need to backfill via a batch update?

Comment: Are you checking it correctly? You should get *null* instead of *false*.

Comment: Just a gentle reminder: Normally you have to get explicit permission from people to subscribe them to an email list. So do you _really_ want to default your `subscribe` column with `true`? (Even if this is a request from a superior you are still responsible for compliance with legal requirements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two way you can do this.

- You can create a program, which will select all record from email_subscriptions and insert back along with  subscribe = true value.

  Or
- When selecting subscribe field value, check the value is null with [isNull()](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html#isNull-int-) method (which will return true if the column is null, false otherwise). If true return, it means that subscribe is null and this value not yet inserted, you can treat it as subscribe = true

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to fill back your whole table. Depending on size of your table, you could have problems at querying your table with a simple

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

due to timeouts. Since the partition key is mandatory in an `UPDATE` statement, you have to find a way to spill your partition keys out from that table.

This is the perfect scenario for using the [TOKEN](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useToken.html?hl=token) function. Assuming you did your homework and don't have any too-wide partitions, you can scan all your dataset by splitting it into ranges of partitions. How wide is your range is up to your data. From a general point of view, you need to:

```
SELECT __partition_key_columns__ FROM mytable WHERE 
    TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) >= min_range AND 
    TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) < max_range;
```

and `min_range` and `max_range` go from -2^63 to 2^64-1 (IIRC, using Murmur3) in steps of a guessed window size *W*:

```
SELECT __partition_key_columns__ FROM mytable WHERE TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) >= -2^63 AND TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) < -2^63 + W;
SELECT __partition_key_columns__ FROM mytable WHERE TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) >= -2^63 + W AND TOKEN(__partition_key_columns__) < -2^63 + 2*W;
...
```

until you covered all the range up to 2^64-1. If you get a timeout make *W* smaller and try again. And if you don't, expand your window *W* so you'll speed up the process. You will be able to extract all the partitions to issue the updates for each range.

**EDIT:** [This blog post](http://www.myhowto.org/bigdata/2013/11/04/scanning-the-entire-cassandra-column-family-with-cql/) explains exactly how to perform such task.